# Schengen Visa Application for NRI

Tags: indian-citizens, schengen-visas, applications

I am an Non-Resident Indian Citizen working in Lagos (Nigeria). My Wife, a house-wife, also has Nigerian Resident Permit & my 9 yrs. old Daughter also posses Nigerian Visa, as minor don't need Resident Permit, but most of the time they stay in India maximum.
We want to visit a few Schengen countries for 15 days.
Can I apply for me & my family from Lagos, will it require personal interview/Bio-metric for my family also.
Can we apply from India also but as I am NRI, I don't have ITR for last 3 years, is that mandatory even for NRI.

Comment: What's an ITR??

Comment: ITR=income tax return